# have a problem in receiving emails when user fill them in Arabic

Tags: email, utf-8, arabic-support

I have a contact form at my website which support English / Arabic languages.I got a problem when my customers fill the form in Arabic language..I receive the email content "a lot of question marks" can't detect the Arabic language.
In html the meta tag for support arabic was included

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

for the form I write the form tag :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
```

and in contactme.php this line was included
but still have the problem..need your help please.

[I got email that shows in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsJYQ.png)

Comment: The most likely problem is in your `upload.php`, specifically how it creates the mail. It likely is incorrectly encoding it, or not providing the right headers for the mail. Rather than showing a screenshot of the mail mail, look at the actual email data (including its headers).

Comment: I'm not using an upload.php as I have a simple form use it to get client comments or problems  :(

Comment: The code you show above should pass that text to `upload.php` (that's the action). What sends the email?